# Maintaining precision of while writing data frame to CSV in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In our dataframe -

dataframe before writing to csv

```
name    id  Value
xcv 1   34.6780
vbn 3   9.00000
```

query_result_df.to_csv(filePath, index=False)

values in csv

```
name    id  Value
xcv 1   34.678
vbn 3   9.0
```

I want that both the values in dataframe and csv should be same.

Comment: You should share the data outside of a link.  Paste in a minimal example from both files that users can help you more effectively

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float_format` parameter in to_csv:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', float_format='%f')
```

Output ( !more test.scv ):

```
,name,id,Value
0,xcv,1,34.678900
1,vbn,3,9.000000
```

Comment: it is specific for 5 decimal, i want it to be generic, for any precision

Comment: @RahulBerry Try ='%f'

Comment: It is giving me decimal to six precision, but I want exactly that are in the source data frame, I have updated the question.

Comment: @RahulBerry I am can't see another way other than converting your dataframe to string first then outputing to CSV.